# Recognize special characters in NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, uitextview

I have a UITextView with text:

❡

its image:
[image] (**This is screen shot of my text, I worry somebody can not see my special character**)

If I am an **end-user**, I just see that there are only **7 characters** on textView.

But `[textView.text length]`=**13**

I want to split this text into an array like this:

array = **@[**
[image],
[image],
[image],... **]**

But I can't detect where [image] is, where [image] is, where [image] is ... :(

Could you help me!

Comment: you can log the lengh of images you added into textview to see why `[textView.text length] = 13`. sample code: `UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sample.png"];
 NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0); 
 NSLog(@"Size of Image(bytes):%d",[imgData length]);`

Comment: Thanks lee! But I think you didn't understand what I mean. I've edited my post. Please read it again :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Characters outside of the ["basic multilingual plane"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Multilingual_Plane#Basic_Multilingual_Plane) - in other words, characters whose
Unicode value is greater than `U+FFFF` - are stored in `NSString` as *two* UTF-16 characters,
a so-called *surrogate pair*.

For example, "" = U+1F44C (OK HAND SIGN)
is stored in `NSString` as the two characters U+D83D, U+DC4C.

To correctly split a string with surrogate pairs, use the

```
enumerateSubstringsInRange:options:usingBlock:
```

method of `NSString` with the `NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences` option.

Another useful method is `rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex:` to determine the
range of a composed character sequence at a certain position.