# Way to detect character that takes up more than one index spot in an NSString?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsstring

I'm wondering, is there a way to detect a character that takes up more than 1 index spot in an NSString? (like an emoji). I'm trying to implement a custom text view and when the user pushes delete, I need to know if I should delete only the previous one index spot or more.

Comment: @trojanfoe - Whatever the standard is? I'm just working with a regular NSString, nothing fancy.

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22499381/recognize-special-characters-in-nsstring.

Comment: You need to be specific as to whether you mean 2 bytes long (which would be one Objective-C `CHAR` or 2 `CHAR`s long.

Comment: @HotLicks - I meant 2 char long, so should I change to 4 bytes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually `NSString` use `UTF-16`.So it is quite difficult to work with characters which takes `two UTF-16 charater(unichar) or more`.But you can do with `rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex`to get range and than delete.

First find the last character index from string

```
NSUInteger lastCharIndex = [str length] - 1;
```

Than get the range of last character

```
NSRange lastCharRange = [str rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex: lastCharIndex];
```

Than delete with range from  character (If it is of two UTF-16 than it deletes UTF-16)

```
deletedLastCharString = [str substringToIndex: lastCharRange.location];
```

**You can use this method with any type of `characters` which takes any number of unichar**

Comment: It is not hard to find out how many bytes a character takes up. If you convert the string to `UTF8` char array it's fairly easy if you know a bit about the UTF8 encoding.

Comment: As the question says how delete the characters so this method does that.It can delete any `unicode` character taking any number of `unichars`.No need to convert `UTF8` or work with `UTF8`

Answer (score 1):

For one you could transform the string to a sequence of characters using `[myString UTF8String]` and you can then check if the character has its first bit set to one or zero. If its one then this is a UTF8 character and you can then check how many bytes are there to this character. Details about UTF8 can be found on [Wikipedia - UTF8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). Here is a simple example:

```
NSString *string = @"ČTest";
const char *str = [string UTF8String];
NSMutableString *ASCIIStr = [NSMutableString string];

for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); ++i)
    if (!(str[i] & 128))
        [ASCIIStr appendFormat:@"%c", str[i]];

NSLog(@"%@", ASCIIStr); //Should contain only ASCII characters
```